# Ayuda al introducir varios datos en Android

Tags: java, android

necesito ayuda al cargar varios datos mediante un TextView, estoy haciendo un proyecto que me pidieron en la Universidad es de la materia Investigación Operativa no se si ya lo conocerán pero tengo que hacer una proyecto para esa materia, mi problema es que no se como puedo ingresar varios datos a mi aplicación

[image: En aquí pido el numero de variables y el numero de restricciones]

En donde dice numero de variables pues ingreso el numero de variables y donde dice numero de restricciones pues ingreso el numero de restricciones.

[image: En aquí ya ingreso el numero de variables y el numero de restricciones]

Una vez que ingreso el numero de variables y el numero de restricciones quiero que internamente se cree una matriz con los valores que ingrese, en  este caso en la imagen introduci:  numero de variables:2 y numero de restricciones:2 por lo cual se debería crear una matriz de 2x2 y quiero que cada vez que yo presione el botón CARGAR cada dato que ingrese en el EditText se cargue en la matriz que se creo.En Java Eclipse seria algo así:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        matriz[i][j]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un numero");
    }
}
```

Con eso yo tranquilamente lo cargo en la matriz pero como puedo hacer algo así en Android Studio??? Espero que me hayan entendido, fui lo mas claro posible, espero sus respuestas...Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Quedaria asi con el enfoque que quieres usar:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        matrixInput(matriz,i,j,"Ingrese un numero:");
    }
}
```

donde defines la funcion matrixInput asi:

```
void matrixInput(final double [][] matriz,final int i,final int j,String msg) {
    final EditText txtNum = new EditText(this);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Ingrese un numero:")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setView(txtNum)                
            .setPositiveButton("Ingresar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String num = txtNum.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        matriz[i][j] = Double.valueOf(num);
                    }catch (NumberFormatException nf){
                        matrixInput(matriz,i,j,"Repita el numero, el formato es incorrecto");
                    }
                }
            }
            ).show();
}
```

Faltaria validar que no cancelen el dialogo, aunque este no es el mejor enfoque en cuanto a diseño de UI ni tampoco usar JOptionPane.showInputDialog para cuatro o mas valores